# Play framework 1.2.x @MinSize custom validation message

Tags: java, validation, playframework

I know that I can do a custom validation message for the @ Required annotation in the Play model layer, like this:

```
@Required(message = "customError.required")
public String name;
```

But I tried to do the same for the @MinSize annotation...

```
@MinSize(8)(message = "customError.passwordSoShort")
public String password;
```

... and recieved this compilation error:

```
The file /app/models/User.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : Syntax error on token ")", ? expected
@MinSize(8)↓(message = "customError.passwordSoShort")
public String password;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error with your code.

Try with:

```
@MinSize(value=8, message = "customError.passwordSoShort")
public String password;
```